# How do I join two objects without having the modifiers disappear?

Tags: modifiers, objects

How could I join two object and maintain the modifiers?

[image]

Once I join the roof and walls, the straw (which is done as modifier) disappears.

[image]

Is there solution for it this?

Comment: The last object you select is the one that will keep its modifiers. You can't keep the modifiers of the other objects, so maybe apply them?

Comment: Yea I just hoped there''s better way to approach this issue, thanks for the reply thoug!

Comment: why do you want to join mesh into one?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the modifiers tab on the side and press the apply button.

Please note that modifiers won't actually change the mesh of your object until you apply them. Before that it will just show you what it would look like in the viewport. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wasn't awaare of it !